# Use of Conjectures to Prove a Theorem

Tags: lo.logic, mathematical-philosophy

Name a theorem T that has a proof based upon the truth of a conjecture C, and also has another proof based upon the falsehood of the same conjecture C, but for longtime has no known direct proof that is independent of C. For instance, it would be a claim that can be proved if P=NP, and can also be proved if P is different from NP.
I apologize if the question was previously asked (I also apologize for the title if it does not faithfully reflect the question).

Comment: Shouldn't any such two proofs be able to be rewritten as cases?

Comment: @wzzx: it would in the end be a proof by cases. But for example, I dimly remember a book (number theory or algebraic geometry almost certainly) that talked about a major conjecture; it was first proven by one person that the conjecture was a consequence of the Riemann hypothesis being true; some years later, someone else proved that the conjecture would also follow from assuming the Riemann hypothesis was false. This final link was, of course, seen together with the original work as a proof of the original conjecture. Perhaps someone can fill in my dim memory... or I'll try to find it Monday.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: That is the Gauss class number problem. See my answer.

Comment: @Anweshi: Aha! Yes, that sounds exactly like what I would have read; sorry I didn't notice it when I posted my comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are asking for an example of such a method in action, then you have the theorem of Hecke-Deuring-Heilbronn that $h(D) \rightarrow \infty$ as $D \rightarrow \infty$, where $h(D)$ is the class number of the imaginary quadratic field with discriminant $D$.

The Hecke part is that the result is true if there are no Siegel zeros of L-functions for imaginary quadratic fields. Siegel zeros are exceptional zeros occurring in the real line in the interval $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$. The Deuring-Helbronn part is that the result is true if there are Siegel zeros. The proof uses an effect of "repulsion" of such zeros, which is called the Deuring-Heilbronn phenomenon. This is all explained by Dorian Goldfeld in a bulletin article, "[Gauss' Class number problem for Imaginary Quadratic Fields](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1985-13-01/S0273-0979-1985-15352-2/)".

The existence of Siegel zeros is a stronger version of the negation of the Generalized Riemann hypothesis. Hopefully in future the generalized Riemann hypothesis would be proved and thus hopefully it will be shown that the study of Sigel zeros had been just the study of the empty set.

---

Later story(added just for additional information): This method was later strengthened by Landau, Siegel and so on, and finally with more recent developments on the Birch-Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture by Gross and Zagier, an effective version of this theorem was proved by Dorian Goldfeld, and the explicit constants were computed by Joseph Oesterlé. Thus the Gauss class number problem was solved in its entirety.

Thanks to Keith Conrad for correcting ambiguities.

Comment: It's also in the book "Multiplicative Number Theory" by Harold Davenport, in the chapter called "Siegel's Theorem." I won't be the only one to notice that "Deuring-Heilbronn Phenomenon" is an excellent name for a rock band.

Comment: @Will: needs more umlauts.  Deuring-Heilbrönn Phenömenön?

Comment: The closest I could find:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5Mc55P1i9g 

Comment: Also see  http://www.davebarry.com/rockbandlist.html   

Comment: It's frustrating to figure out what "GRH is false" means when it is not indicated which $L$-functions are intended. Presumably the only ones that matter are those attached to odd quadratic Dirichlet characters, e.g., Heilbronn couldn't use a violation of GRH for the L-function of a cubic Dirichlet character.  Moreover, the Hecke and Heilbronn proofs require a nontrivial real zero, not any nontrivial zero. So it's too strong (but not wrong) to say Hecke assumes GRH is true and it's too weak (i.e., it's wrong) to say Heilbronn assumes GRH is false. Only counterexamples in (1/2,1) matter.

Comment: So I would say that the theorem which is actually assumed true or false here is "There are no nontrivial *real* zeros of $L$-functions attached to *imaginary* quadratic fields," i.e., "There are no Siegel zeros of $L$-functions for imag. quadratic fields." That is still an open problem, but it is not GRH.

Comment: @KConrad. I had just followed the terminology of Goldfeld. Since he was himself the theorem prover, I thought these usages would be standard.

Comment: What is standard is to find "Assuming GRH..." in theorems without care about precisely what aspect is being assumed (e.g., which L-functions, which zero-free regions), so at worst a casual reader may carry along a hypothesis which is too strong. Alas, when you negate things that makes your hypothesis insufficient. There are, understandably, few theorems which assume GRH is false, so there really isn't a standard on that and we see that applying the usual vague wording from the positive theorems to this setting is not a good model.

Comment: (@user35353 "Weaker" is correct here. A weaker version of the negation of GRH, so the opposite statement, the one we believe true, is stronger. Still, Keith Conrad's remark is appropriate.)

Comment: @Andres Caicedo:
(1) GRH implies no Siegel zeroes, therefore
(2) existence of Siegel zeroes implies failure of GRH, therefore
(3) existence of Siegel zeroes is stronger than failure of GRH.
I think this is consistent with KConrad's comments.

Comment: more succinctly: there are ways for GRH to fail other than there being a Siegel zero, so asking for the latter is stronger.

Comment: @user35353 Sure, OK. Somewhat awkward phrasing, unfortunately. I've rolled back to your edit, sorry for the added noise.

Answer (score 31):

Another standard example is Littlewood's theorem that the number of primes less than x is sometimes greater than Li(x). His proof used different arguments depending on whether the Riemann hypothesis is true or false. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27_number

Comment: This must be the one I remembered. I just found it, again, in section 12.4 of Riemann's Zeta Function by H. M. Edwards. Not in Hardy and Wright, though.

Answer (score 22):

How about this basic one:

Theorem: There exists an irrational number $p$ and an irrational number $q$ such that $p^q$ is rational.

Proof: Let $q=\sqrt{2}$ and note that it is irrational.  Conjecture: $q^q$ is irrational.  If this conjecture is false, then we are done (the theorem is proved with $p=q$).  If the conjecture is true, then let $p=q^q$ and note that it is irrational.  The theorem is true in this case as well since $$p^q=(\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}})^{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}^2=2$$ is rational.

Comment: I don't think that this conjecture is not solved.

Comment: But it's cool, anyhow.

Comment: $$ 2^{\sqrt 2} $$ is transcendental by Gelfond-Schneider. Therefore 
$$ {\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2} = \left( 2^{\frac{1}{2 }} \right)^{\sqrt 2} =  \left( 2^{\sqrt 2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2 }} $$
is transcendental.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem
$$ $$
On this and related topics, I really like "Irrational Numbers" by Ivan Niven, available in paperback from the M.A.A.
Gelfond-Schneider and Hermite-Lindemann are proved, history given etc.


Comment: Live and learn. $$ 2^{\sqrt 2} $$ was first proved transcendental by Kuzmin in 1930, so it was a near thing.  
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_constant
which also discusses David's example.